# Downloaded image file is corrupt

Tags: lua

I'm making a simple Lua script to download images. I get the URL of the image, and then this is my code to download it:

```
content = http.request(imageurl)
file = io.open("E:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\Lua\\IMGDownload\\output.jpg", "w")
file:write(content)

print("Wrote content")
```

I get a 4KB file, however it isn't what I want it to be.

For reference, here is the image that I want to download:

[RealImage http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/bd/bd05e23129b5d03ecb3f933589ff1477fbff4e92_full.jpg](http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/bd/bd05e23129b5d03ecb3f933589ff1477fbff4e92_full.jpg)

This is what I actually get:

[image: ActualImage]

Can anyone pinpoint me as to the cause?

Comment: Do you need `"wb"` on the `io.open` call to open the file in binary mode?

Comment: Ah yes, that was it! Thank you so much. Now, what do I do with this question? (I'm new to the site)

Comment: I added the solution as an answer. At some point you should be able to check the checkmark next to the answer to accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to open the file with `"wb"` mode to get Windows to open the file in binary mode and not do line-ending conversion on you.

Try `io.open("E:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\Lua\\IMGDownload\\output.jpg", "wb")`.